# Onmouseover <li> change the color of span: first-child color

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover

I am getting problem **here:**

```
<ul id="parentnode">
   <li><span>I need color change here</span><span>no color</span><span>nocolor</span></li>
   <!-- continuing li tags from database -->
</ul>
```

Here, `Onmouseover` `<li>` tag i have to change the color of **text** which is inside the `<span>`  `first-child`.
 Is it possible to change through **Javascript**, How ?

**Note:** It is not possible to give **id's** to `<li>` tag or `<span>` tag, because they are dynamically presenting from database.

Thank you.

Comment: @Ran: See my answer, how is it possible with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by the following css

```
#parentnode li:first-child:hover span:first-child { color: red; }​
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/CgCVP)

*EDIT: link was invalid, removed slash

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your CSS:

```
ul#parentnode > li:first-child:hover > span:first-child {
    color: blue;
}
```

and change "blue" with whatever color you want

Comment: It will change the color of span (first-child) inside every `li` as OP wants only first child

Comment: the `li:first-child` part should take care of that, influencing only the first span in the first li of parentnode, and I used the direct child selector so that only the first level of `li`s and the first sublevel of `span`s would be affected.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul#parentnode > li:first-child:hover > span:first-child {
    color: ;
}
```